# Vue 3 JS & Vee-Validate ; use of useField() and creation of a Dynamic Form Component

Tags: javascript, dynamic, vuejs3, vue-component, vee-validate

I am developing a large app using Vue 3 JS for the Frontend (and Django and DRF for the API in the backend).

Since I am going to have many forms to generate for the CRUD system, I am trying to develop a 'Form Component' that would be dynamically creating forms for a given array of Fields.

I am almost there, but the thing I can not get my head around is the use of useField().

Basically, I am trying to replace the following code with a loop:

```
    const {value:email1 } = useField('email1')
    const {value:password} = useField('password')
    const {value:password2} = useField('password2')
    const {value:first_name} = useField('first_name')
    const {value:last_name} = useField('last_name')
```

I need it to come up with my dynamic component.
I naively tried :

```
 const a = ['email1','password','password2','first_name','last_name']

    essai.forEach((val,key)=>{
        console.log(val)
        console.log(useField(val).value)
        const {value:val} = useField(a[key])
    })
```

But, of course, it does not work...
useField is a reactive object and I have difficulties to play around with it.

I have tried with this doc, but I have trouble understanding it: [Vee Validate Composition API Caveats](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/composition-api/caveats/)

The error I am getting is this:

[image: Snapshot of the error message]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: After looking more deeply into the doc, I found the solution to this issue. It was simply to move useField (that allows an abstraction of Field) into the Base Component... I found the inspiration here in the Vee-Validate doc

Answer (score 0):

Edit on August, 8th 2023: I found the solution here:

[Build a Form Generator](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/tutorials/dynamic-form-generator/)

The solution was simply to move useField (which is an abstraction of Field) to the Base Component instead of within the parent component (Form). Now, I am able to generate forms on the fly with all the validation features.